# Laravel Ajax POST 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I'm trying to add a new row to my datatable with ajax
This is my modal for adding a new row:

```
<div id="modal-add-team" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" novalidate>
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                <div class="col-sm "><h3 class="text-center m-t-none m-b">Add Team</h3>

                    <p>Add Team</p>

                        <div class="form-group"><label>Team Name</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>   @if ($errors->has('name')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</p> @endif
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group"><label>Parent Team</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Niche" class="form-control" id="parent-id" name="parent-id"></div>   


                        <button id="addTeam" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right m-t-n-xs" type="submit"  style="width: 100%;" onclick="pressOnlyOnce()" ><strong>Add</strong></button>

                    </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{ url('/ajax/add-team') }}',
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'parent_id': $('input[name=parent_id]').val()
        },

        success: function(data) {
            if ((data.errors)){
                $('.error').removeClass('hidden');
                $('.error').text(data.errors.name);
            }
            else {
                $('.error').addClass('hidden');
                window.location.href='{{ url('/teams') }}';
                $('#table').append("<tr class='item" + data.id + "'><td>" + data.id + "</td><td>" + data.name + "</td><td><button class='edit-modal btn btn-info' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-name='" + data.name + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button> <button class='delete-modal btn btn-danger' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-name='" + data.name + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete</button></td></tr>");
            }
        },

    });
    $('#name').val('');
```

But it doesn't even reach the point where it goes to my controller. It just says that error 500... Where did I go wrong?

Comment: As the error say it's a server error. Can you provide the laravel log located in storage/logs?

Comment: @Wistar it's really long but here's a snippet: 2017-02-28 02:54:07] production.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\linqs\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\linqs\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php(43): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'forge', '', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\linqs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php(116):

Comment: Your database is configured wrong